# How to stop Automated Email Marketing Reminder within Magento Enterprise from backdating

Tags: php, magento, email, enterprise

We're looking into the functionality for Abandoned baskets provided within Magento Enterprise, we've setup our rule to say when a basket has been abandoned for or greater than one day.

This rule then matches 3000+ previous customers who we do not want to send emails but the system attempts to. (We've stopped this by removing the transactional email code whilst we test).

How do we force the system to only send out emails to new abandoned baskets and to not backdate through previous data?

**Solution:**
In the end we modified the core code temporarily to remove the functionality which was sending the email. This allowed the system to still mark that entry as sent but without sending the email. After we reverted our core changes back and enabled the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let it backdate through previous data because why not.. The customer might still return if the basket has been abandoned for greater than one day.

I don't see any other option than creating your own condition. Something like:

> Shopping cart is not empty and abandoned for or **less** than  14  days
>   and ALL  of these conditions match:

Comment: We didn't want to do a complete backdate as we have been running this site for around a year. In the end we modified the code, removing the part that sent the email and then 'backdated' all the old data. This set the 'email sent' flag to true so when we enabled the code again it wouldn't resend the emails.